# C# HttpClient.PostAsync doesn't return or throw an error

Tags: c#, http, windows-services

I have a Windows service making an HTTP POST request. The REST endpoint is working and it was tested separately. After calling `PostAsync`, the debugger doesn't continue or throw an error. What would be the possible issues which cause this behavior? Following is the code snippet sending the POST request,

**EDIT: I've changed this to async-await and used `ConfigureAWait`, but this didn't solve the problem. I need to know what is causing the function to not return any value.**

```
HttpClientHandler handler = GetCookieHandler();
using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler)) {
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("basic", accessToken);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("UniqueId", _configReader.UniqueId);

    SetRequestCookie(handler);

    string jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);

    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;

    SaveCookie(handler, response.RequestMessage.RequestUri);

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
        var customerJsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Error data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Error > (customerJsonString);

        switch (data.ErrorCode) {
        case AccessTokenValidationCodes.ExpiredOrInvalidDateTime:
            logger.Warn("Expired AccessToken");
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
        logger.Error("Request :{0}, AccessToken {1}  response Unauthorized", apirUrl, accessToken);
        return null;
    }
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) {
        logger.Warn("Request response InternalServerError");
        return null;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpClient PostAsync() never return response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078296/httpclient-postasync-never-return-response)

Comment: I looked into this before posting this but changing to async-await and ConfigureAwait(false) didn't do much.

Comment: Can you include the function's signature. And, btw; it's better to add the async await pattern in most cases.

Comment: `public HttpResponseMessage PostSync(string apirUrl, object content)`


This is the function signature

Answer (score 1):

Further to my duplicate comment, you need to read the response to the end. At current you only do this if Unauthorised, but you should read to end regardless. Make sure you take [the advice from the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34078296/httpclient-postasync-never-return-response), including the one on async await, and also:

Move the ReadAsString line out and make sure it runs for all calls to the endpoint.

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result; 
 var customerJsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Your code

```
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) {
        var customerJsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        Error data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Error > (customerJsonString);

        switch (data.ErrorCode) {    
            case AccessTokenValidationCodes.ExpiredOrInvalidDateTime:
                logger.Warn("Expired AccessToken");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
```

Comment: The debugger is not executing after `.PostAsync`, the call stack just disappears, so I guess the issue is related to how I call `.PostAsync()`, not how I get the result?

Comment: I suggest you convert to a full async pattern.  You can test and try wrapping your async code in Task.Run(). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14435520/why-use-httpclient-for-synchronous-connection  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53529061/whats-the-right-way-to-use-httpclient-synchronously and try getting a different endpoint...